# How to configure Web Deploy to grant publish permissions for a single application?

Tags: iis-8.5

We have a new user that needs to be able to deploy a specific website to a specific application directory (Default Web Site/WebX) but I cannot seem to configure Web Deploy on IIS without giving them the ability to publish to all directories (e.g. Default Web Site/WebOther).

How can we limit the permissions to allow the user to deploy to only a specific application?